# Prove that $|1/x| = 1/|x|$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, absolute-value

First time posting on here. Started a class with proof based calculus using Spivak's Calculus.
This problem is from the first chapter on proving absolute values.

Below is my attempt at a solution, there is a hint under the question which says to look at the exponent but I couldn't figure it out doing that.

Can anyone guide me here, I'm doing a second degree in applied mathematics after being away from school for almost a decade

$$\require{cancel} \begin{aligned}|x| &=\sqrt{x^{2}} \text { for all } x \in R \\\left|\frac{1}{x}\right| &=\frac{1}{|x|} \\ \cancel{\sqrt{x^2} }\left(\frac{\sqrt{(1)^{2}}}{\cancel{\sqrt{x^{2}}}}\right) &=\left(\frac{1}{\cancel{\sqrt{x^{2}}}}\right)(\cancel{\sqrt{x^2}}) \\ \sqrt{(1)^{2}} &=1 \\ 1 &=1 \end{aligned}$$

Comment: Hi Sam, if I remember Spivak correctly, he doesn't define $\sqrt{x}$ at this point, so if you're following Spivak, you can't use it in a proof, in particular I don't think that is Spivak's definition of $|x|$. Also I typed up your image, you can learn how to type mathematics on this website in [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Proof does not look right to me. You can't just set them equal and manipulate the equation. You need to show that the left side (|1/x|) and right side are equal 1/(|x|). A few ways to do this: 1. Manipulate the left side alone making it look like the right side. 2. Manipulate the right side alone to make it look like the left side. 3. Manipulate the left side to make it look like something. Manipulate the right side to also make it look like that same something.

Comment: Use the basic definition of absolute value. Consider x=0, x>0 and x<0 separately. Under each condition show that the left side and right side are the same. The definition of absolute value should let you get rid of the absolute value signs.

Comment: A preceding problem has you show $\lvert xy \rvert = \lvert x \rvert \lvert y \rvert$, for any 2 numbers $x$ and $y$. See if you can apply this result to the numbers $x$ and $\frac{1}{x}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Case 1: $x=0$

$\frac{1}{x}$ is undefined.

LS = $|\frac{1}{x}|$. This is undefined since $\frac{1}{x}$ is undefined.

RS = $\frac{1}{|x|} = \frac{1}{|0|} = \frac{1}{0}$. This is also undefined.

So both sides are undefined.

Case 2: $x>0$

$\frac{1}{x} > 0$. This is because a positive number, divided by a positive number, is always positive. (not sure if this requires some proof also).

LS = $|\frac{1}{x}| = \frac{1}{x}$ since $\frac{1}{x}$ is positive.

RS = $\frac{1}{|x|} = \frac{1}{x}$ since $x$ is positive.

LS = RS.

Case 3: x<0

$\frac{1}{x} < 0$. This is because a positive number divided by a negative number is negative.

LS = $|\frac{1}{x}| = -\frac{1}{x}$, since $\frac{1}{x}<0$

RS = $\frac{1}{|x|} = \frac{1}{-x}$ since $x<0$

Then we can bring the negative outside the fraction

RS = $-\frac{1}{x}$

LS = RS.

So in all 3 cases the left and right sides are equal.